# Метод отсутствует в aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, telegram

Мне нужно получить всю информацию о сообщении зная лишь его `id` с помощью бота. Раньше в своём юзерботе я использовал метод `messages.getMessages` с библиотекой `pyrogram`,
но в `aiogram`е я его найти никак не могу.
В самом документации сказано что боты могут использовать этот api метод (https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.getMessages)
я даже поискал этот метод в библиотеках которые показаны в сайте самого телеграмма (https://core.telegram.org/bots/samples#python)
но там его тоже нет.

Comment: https://github.com/aiogram/aiogram/issues/1073 - Со стандартным api telegram и aiogram это не возможно.

Comment: но в документациях написано что болты могут использовать этот метод

Comment: боты*ㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤ